# Override variables in JSTL

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm trying to make pagination.

I have some variable `get_page_num`:

```jsp
<c:set var="get_page_num"/>

<spring:url value="" var="pageurl">
<spring:param name="page" value="${get_page_num}" />
<spring:param name="size" value="${page.size}" />
</spring:url>
```

After that, I'm trying to generate the url:

```jsp
<li><a href="${pageurl}">7</a></li> 
<li><a href="${pageurl}">8</a></li>
```

How can I put 7 or 8 value (number of page) to `get_page_num` variable. I need to override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values 7,8 are already generated, you can get em only with javascript.

Use parameter in the url

```jsp
<li><a href="${pageurl}?get_page_num=7">7</a></li>
```

In more sophisticated code you can write

```jsp
<spring:url value="" var="pageurl" />
<c:forEach begin="1" end="${page.size}" varStatus="status">
 <c:if test="${get_page_num == status.current}">
   ${status.current}&nbsp;
 </c:if>
 <c:if test="${get_page_num != status.current}">
   <li><a href="${pageurl}?get_page_num=${status.current}">${status.current}&nbsp;</a></li>
 </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Many thanks, it will be useful) But it's not an answer to my topic. Is it possible to override the JSTL variable after, for example, <c:set var="a" value="1"/> ?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Is it answer to your question or it's another question?